# How to filter based on a certain column in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have the following problem: I want to filter a list of clients based on their phone number.

My actual output:

```
id  firstname  lastname phonenumber creation date 
1      client    client   664433      2020/01/02
2      client    client   664433      2020/01/02
3      client    client   664432      2020/01/02
4      client    client   669433      2020/01/02
5      client    client   964433      2020/01/02
6      client    client   664033      2020/01/02
```

As you can see, there are phone numbers duplicated.

My desired output should be:

```
id  firstname  lastname phonenumber creation date 
1      client    client   664433      2020/01/02
2      client    client   664432      2020/01/02
3      client    client   669433      2020/01/02
4      client    client   964433      2020/01/02
5      client    client   664033      2020/01/02
```

Here is the code I'm using in order to identify these duplicated numbers and remove them from my output:

```
select 
cc.id ,
cc."FirstName", 
cc."LastName", 
cc."PhoneNumber" as phone_number,
case when cc."PhoneNumber" is not null count(cc."PhoneNumber") else 0,
cc."CreationDate"
from souscritootest.public.clients_crm cc
having count(cc."PhoneNumber") = 1
;
```

The problem is that I'm getting this feedback from the IDE: `SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "count"  Position: 128`

What I want to do is create a column with the case when to tag with a 1 if it's duplicated and 0 if it's not duplicated.

Thanks!

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Could you please provide sample data and desired output, because "I want to filter a list of clients based on their phone number" is absent in your non-working query

Comment: Why *wouldn't* you expect `(select distinct cc."PhoneNumber" from souscritootest.public.clients_crm cc)` to yield multiple phone numbers?

Comment: What do you want to happen if a client has several phone no's?

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

To get a distinct list of values, you just need to use the `DISTINCT` keyword.

`SELECT DISTINCT cc.Id...`

Though this is the correct answer to your question, I suspect that the client names are not all "client client" with the same creation date. Which means you probably have some clients with the same phone number. In that case, which client would you want to show? Take a look at this example data to get a better grasp on the issue:

```
id  firstname  lastname phonenumber creation date 
1   Joel       Foo      664433      2020/01/02
2   John       Bar      664433      2020/01/03
3   Angelo     Foobar   664432      2020/01/04
```

In this case we would want to remove the duplicate phone number `664433`, but which name would we want to show for the number: Joel or John?

Removing duplicates in the query might solve your problem, but could produce a bigger one later. I would recommend not allowing duplicate phone numbers in the first place if the requirements are to not have them.

Comment: Hello I don't get this "fooNumber" thing, can you please explain? I'm still in trouble to filter duplicate phone numbers

Comment: Are you trying to filter duplicate phone numbers or duplicate _clients_? The table design seems to have a one-to-one relationship with phone numbers to clients, so duplicate values should be enforced by the schema using constraints. I'll modify my response, but I think you'll still have issues.